# Customize widget for a form in ModelView in flask-admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I have a model `News`:

```
class News(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'news'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String)
    active_from = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    active_until = db.Column(db.DateTime)
```

which gets integrated into `flask-admin` like so:

```
class MyModelView(ModelView):
    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user.usergroup.name == 'admin'

admin.add_view(MyModelView(News, db.session))
```

but when I open my admin page I see an `input type='text'` widget for `news.content`. How can I put a `textarea` there instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the code, `db.String` columns are [mapped](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/form.py#L270) to StringFields, and `db.Text` columns are [mapped](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/form.py#L285) to TextAreaFields, which present the user with [text inputs](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/model/widgets.py#L102) and [textareas](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/model/widgets.py#L104), respectively.

To overwrite this behavior, you can set the [`form_overrides`](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/mod_model/?highlight=form_overrides#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.form_overrides) field:

```
from wtforms.fields import TextAreaField

class MyModelView(ModelView):
    form_overrides = dict(string=TextAreaField)
    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user.usergroup.name == 'admin'
```

Comment: `dict(string=TextAreaField)` This had no effect in my code, don't know why. But changing the `db.Field` to `db.String` in the Model declaration made it work.